# Совершенный вид — преминул, несовершенный —?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, глаголы

> Он не преминул обратиться к публике.

А как подчеркнуть повторяемость действия в прошлом, используя однокоренное *преминуть* слово? Возможно ли это? Если нет, то какие есть варианты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. Нету у этого глагола специальной формы несовершенного вида. 
Впрочем, полагаю, глагол можно в разговорном стиле считать семантически двухвидовым (хотя грамматически таковым, судя по всему, не является).

***"Несколько раз не преминул"*** слух не режет.

Добавлю. В современной речи глагол "преминуть" употребляется только с инфинитивом смыслового глагола. А вот этот глагол может быть и совершенного, и несовершенного вида. "Не преминул сделать" и "не преминул делать". Второе, хоть и вызывает некоторые грамматические сомнения, видимо, может также служить заменой для отсутствующей формы несовершенного вида.

В нацкорпусе есть несколько примеров сочетания "не премунул + несов. вид", в основном старые и потому небесспорные, ибо за последние два-три века многие глаголы испытывали колебания в грамматическом виде. Но вот как минимум один сомнений не вызывает

> , волок его из шалаша, причем ***не преминул оделять*** пощечинами и
>   позатыльщинами с таким проворством, какое может только внушить
>   оскорбленная любовь и обманутое ожидание.

[В. Т. Нарежный. Бурсак (1822)] 
Вот она, ваша искомая повторяемость.

Comment: Я скорее имел в виду что-то типа They always did not fail to appeal to the public..., но все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать так:

**Он никогда не преминет обратиться к публике.**

Пример

Добро бы хорь, который таскает цыплят (но который, кстати сказать, в конечном счете тем же крестьянам приносит больше пользы, нежели вреда), ну ладно, если бы мышь или крыса, которых **никогда не преминет** убить крестьянин, а то и всего-то невинная белочка, с пушистым хвостом, с милой мордочкой, с не менее милыми передними лапками. [В. А. Солоухин. Смех за левым плечом (1989)]

ПРЕМИНУТЬ, -ну, -нешь; св. (только с отриц. и инф.). Устар. Не упустить случая, возможности сделать что-л. Я не преминул явиться на совещание. Не премину воспользоваться Вашим разрешением. **Всегда не преминет** поблагодарить её.

Comment: Спасибо, правда, я говорил о прошлом...